# Angularjs hide row if another row is selected

Tags: angularjs, hide, show

I have a html/angularjs table that contains the ff :

```
 <tbody ng-repeat="x in Persons">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{x.FirstName}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.LastName}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.Department}}</td>                           
                        <td>
                            <a href"#" data-ng-click="x.show = !x.show">
                             Sales Details
                            </a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td ng-show="x.show">
                        <!--user sales details here-->
                     </td>
                    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Currently, if I click on the first row it shows the details but I need to click it again to hide it. I want to hide the first row details if the 2nd row is clicked. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. i hope this what exactly what you want.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("name", function($scope) {
 $scope.Persons=[{"FirstName":"Ramesh","show":false},{FirstName:"Suresh","show":false}];
 $scope.showorhide = function(index){
 var currentOption=$scope.Persons[index].show;
  $scope.Persons.forEach(x=>x.show=false);
  $scope.Persons[index].show=!currentOption;
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="name">
<table>
<tbody ng-repeat="x in Persons">
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name</td>                   
                        <td>
                            <a href"#/" style="color:red" ng-click="showorhide($index)">
                           open/close
                            </a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-show="x.show">
                     <td >
                        {{x.FirstName}}
                     </td>
                    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need a method for this

take a look
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-tv6dog?file=index.js

js:

```
$scope.clicked = function(index){
 let currentOption=$scope.Persons[index].show;
 $scope.Persons.forEach(x=>x.show=false);
 $scope.Persons[index].show=!currentOption;
}
```

html

```
<td>
  <a href"#" data-ng-click="clicked($index)">
  Sales Details
 </a>
</td>
```

and of course add track by to ng-repeat

```
<tbody ng-repeat="x in Persons track by $index">
```

Comment: It wont allow hide the same row. It has been a row always in view mode.

Comment: 1 Now it's clear. That's what i provided in my answer. :)